# Error 500 en script php (Internal Server Erro)

Tags: php

Acabo de subir hace un día una web desarrollada por mi nomas. Pero da error en el script de login.php.

Error 500: Internal Server Error.

El servidor esta trabajando con php 7. Pero la verdad no se que puede ser, En local en mi computadora anduvo perfecto obviamente.

la página es www.ottracerveza.com

en index.php tengo:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>GESTION OTTRA</title>
       
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
       
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylos.css"/>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylos.css" />
        <script src="includes/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
       
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<?php session_start(); ?>


        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="views/login.js"></script>
    

      <?php       
        require_once("routes.php");
         
if ( isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['userid']) ){



    if (isset($_GET['controller'])&&isset($_GET['action'])) {
 require_once("views/template.php");
        $controller=$_GET['controller'];

        $action=$_GET['action'];
        if (isset($_GET['id'])){
            
            $id=$_GET['id'];
            call($controller,$action,$id);
        }else{
            
        call($controller,$action,0); }

    }else{
        
    } 
}

else{
    echo '<div class="contenedor">
<div class="cabecera">
</div>
<div class="cuerpo">
<div class="panel panel-primary" style="width:50%">
<div class="panel-heading">INGRESE AL SISTEMA</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<label style="color: blue">Usuario:</label></div><div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" style="color:blue" name="login_username" id="login_username" /></div>
           
          </div><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-4">
                <label style="color: blue">Contraseña:</label></div><div class="col-sm-4">
             <input type="password" name="login_userpass" id="login_userpass" style="color:blue" />
        </div>
        </div>
         <div class="row"><div class="col-sm-4">
             <span class="timer" id="timer"></span><button id="login_userbttn" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button></div>
              </div>   </div>
</div>
  ';
}
?>
         
   </body>     
</html>
```

Y en proceso login:

```html
<?php

session_start();
  include_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].''/models/claseLogin.php');
  
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

    $U1=new Login();
    $usuario=$_POST['login_username'];
    $pass=$_POST['login_userpass'];
    $arrayu=$U1->User($usuario,$pass);
   
         if (count($arrayu)>0){ 
            
                foreach ($arrayu as $n){
           

         
            $_SESSION['username']=$n['nombre']; 
            $_SESSION['userid']=$n['iduser']; 
             $_SESSION['rol']=$n['rol'];  
             $id=$U1->registroSesion($_SESSION['userid']);
             foreach ($id as $i){
                $idmax=$i['max'];
             
             $_SESSION['idsesion']=$idmax;}
             
                }echo 1;
                }
                else{
                    echo 0;}

?>
```

de hecho uso la variable $_SERVER, también uso PDO.

Comment: Sin código va a ser imposible adivinar dónde está el problema que provoca el error en el login

Comment: ahi agregue el index y procesologin.php les agradezco cualquier ayuda

Comment: Es posible que esta línea include_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].''/models/claseLogin.php'); sea el problema, por un lado sobra una comilla después del punto, y por otro deberías comprobar que URL arroja en el servidor con un echo y comprobar si es correcta.

Comment: Probe cambiar la url y me da error 404 not found osea que esta bien escrito, ya corregi la comilla y es la ruta absoluta y sigue el problema

Comment: Ahora me dice lo siguiente:<html><head>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator at 
 webmaster@ottracerveza.com to inform them of the time this error occurred,
 and the actions you performed just before this error.</p>
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
</body></html>

Comment: Prueba a poner las dos lineas de reporte de errores al inicio para ver si dan alguna información. Si no da errores yo probaría con die; en distintos puntos para determinar dónde se está produciendo el error.

Comment: Como aclaracion tengo un archivo config.ini que tiene el servidor la bd, user y pass y puerto. pro esta bien definido todo

Comment: @Carmen parece que tu comentario es la respuesta a la pregunta. Deberías publicarlo como respuesta (añadiendo una breve descripción de por qué o cómo funciona). Un saludo